# NodeJS UPD / Datagram Socket Receive Buffer Size

Tags: windows, node.js, udp, buffer

I'm using nodejs dgram for a UDP Server . 
http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html

Where I can find or change the socket receive buffer size ?

Comment: You can't. Your client should be responsible for that.

Comment: CLient ! You mean to manage this by making the messages smaller ? 
here's how to do this for windows globally http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-winsock-buffer.html still needs testing if this value is respected